# Visual Studio Debugging

Tags: visual-studio, multithreading, debugging

I have several threads running and I know currently one or many threads are active but it is difficult to find where exactly the execution is happening.

I'm running my application on debug mode, is there any way to break on current position? or any short cut or way to find current execution method (such as a keyboard shortcut or button within a toolbar)?

Edit:

Thanks for the answers, Found good article about VS 2010 debugging

- [Mastering Debugging in Visual Studio 2010 - A Beginner's Guide](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/MasteringInDebugging.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Debug toolbar item has a button to break the execution of all threads (pause like button).
[image]

If clicked the Threads windows (Debug->Windows->Threads [Ctrl+D,T]]) will list the threads and the location of their execution.

Answer (score 1):

You can click on the menu `Debug` then `Break`.